VS Code, GitHub login
I have previous device with VS Code logged in with GitHub account. It has certain settings and extensions I don’t need any more. I bought a new computer so installed all the new extensions and settings I need. Then I signed in using GitHub account and all my new settings and extensions disappeared and give me the settings and extensions of my previous device. How can I change these settings that connected to GitHub to my new settings and extensions?
I tried deleting all settings.json, nothing changed.

I assume if you change all you settings again, this will sync with your account, and you won't have to do it again.

What operating system are you using?


I bought a new computer so installed all the new extensions and settings I need. Then I signed in using git hub account

You should have done this in the opposite way, that is, log-in first and do modification then.
That's the solution to your issue and how to get rid of old settings and extensions.
Or alternatively, start with brand new account and dump the old one.
